# heroku run rake db:migrate error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-migrations

I want do run migration on my app that I have on heroku but I get this error:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.1
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
Migrating to CreateUsers (20120525005302)
Migrating to DeviseCreateUsers (20120611000411)
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PGError: ERROR:  relation "users" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" character varying(255), "reset_password_sent_at" timestamp, "remember_created_at" timestamp, "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0, "current_sign_in_at" timestamp, "last_sign_in_at" timestamp, "current_sign_in_ip" character varying(255), "last_sign_in_ip" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL) 

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I have the following migration files in my github repository

1. 20120525005302_create_users.rb (which is empty, dont know how to remove it)
2. 20120611000411_devise_create_users.rb
3. 20120613140535_create_authentications.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the following is true:

- `20120525005302_create_users.rb` will attempt to create a `users` table in your database.
- `20120611000411_devise_create_users.rb` will also attempt to create a `users` table in the database.
- Your database currently already has a `users` table in it, so the migration fails on the second migration.

To get the `users` table in your database to correspond properly to the `20120611000411_devise_create_users.rb` migration, you can do one of two things:

1. Roll back (or drop) the database, and then run the migrations again. (You can delete the `20120525005302_create_users.rb` if it is empty.)
2. Modify your `20120611000411_devise_create_users.rb` migration to drop any existing `users` table before doing anything else.
3. Modify your `20120611000411_devise_create_users.rb` migration as follows:

   - Instead of creating a `users` table, modify the existing table.
   - Add and modify database components to correspond

Generally, if your application is in an "infant state," then re-creating the database tends to be a quick way to build the initial structure of an application. However if you already have important data in your `users` table, you'll want to keep that and proceed by modifying the `20120611000411_devise_create_users.rb` migration to change the database non-destructively.

**References**

- [Running Rake Commands on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake)
- [RailsGuides: Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Comment: I rollbacked all the migration, i dont have the first migration and I pushed everthing upp to github put it still is there..

Comment: I have now removed the migration file, still get the same error.

Comment: Sounds like the easiest approach would be to apply the changes to your server's database from a fresh database. Also, if you change the behavior of `20120611000411_devise_create_users.rb`, good practice would be to change its name to reflect the behavior (that is, something like `20120611000411_devise_modify_users.rb` or whatever.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you already have table users (probably from create_users migration) that device_create_users is trying to recreate

You can modify your create_device_users migration to just add the fields that you need

Alternatively if its a brand new app with no users you can just drop and try re running all the migraions

Comment: Cant I just delete that migration from my app and github resp.. How do I do that?

Comment: git rm 20120525005302_create_users.rb

git push origin master

heroku run rake db:drop
heroku run rake db:create
heroku run rake db:migrate