# Rails migration fails creating table in Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

As described in the title, I have a migration in my Rails app which creates a table. We have a Postgres database. When I run the migration in development, it fails:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: CREATE TABLE "feedback_questions" ("id" serial primary key, "survey_id" integer, "question_text" text, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL)
```

The migration is long, but the table creation is the first thing that happens. It looks like this:

```
def up
  create_table :feedback_questions do |t|
    t.integer :survey_id
    t.text :question_text

    t.timestamps
  end
  # ...
end
```

It looks to me like this isn't an issue with the migration, but with the database (the error is coming from PG). The error message is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11023645/306084), but it's not saying anything about what's wrong - just that there's an error. (Also, the table doesn't exist yet; I've checked.)

How can I get more data to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message was a red herring. The issue was not with the table creation; the issue was with the format of the migration itself. I was defining a few models in the migration which used tables created in the `#up` method. When rake tried to start the migration, it looked for tables for those rows, and flipped when it couldn't find them. The `create` statement just happened to be the first command *not* run after the error.